# Enemies have zero hp and still live

Tags: epic-battle-fantasy-4

On Epic Battle Fantasy 4 enemies that seem to have their hp bar completely empty still live, but they die after they take one hit. Is this a bug or is it natural?

Comment: That definitely seems like a bug. Does it happen consistently? What enemies is it doing it for?

Comment: @Rob Watts it doesn't happen all the time, but let's say there is a 20% chance of it popping up, the enemies' type is irrelevent, it happens to ANY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, It is a bug.**  However, it is only a minor visual error and **it has no effect on gameplay.**

If the monster has very few HP remaining, the HP bar may appear empty.  As a programmer, I think it is very likely that the number of pixels that are filled in is calculated based on the ratio of current HP / Max HP, and that there was no special handling done if this rounds down to zero.

For example, assume that the HP bar is 300 pixels long *(it may actually be shorter or longer; this number is for illustrative purposes only)*, and that the enemy has 11 HP remaining out of a maximum of 8000.

- (11 / 8000) * 300 = 0.4125
- 0.4125 rounded to the nearest integer is 0

Note that if you have previously scanned this enemy type, you will be able to see their current HP when you hover over the ? icon next to the monster.

I encountered this issue twice yesterday while playing.  In the screenshot below, notice that the Red Clay (2nd monster from the top) has an empty life bar but 8 HP remaining.

[image: screenshot of empty health bar]

Comment: Yeah, when i hover over the "?" it shows the actual hp, i didn't think about it before. Thanks.

Comment: @Vengeance If you found this answer accurate and helpful, can you please accept it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember ever seeing that as played through EBF4. It's definitely not something that should be happening 20% of the time for all enemies. That is definitely a bug of some kind.